# prepare correct position for equation

Tags: equations, positioning

[image: my goal]

Hi all,

I want to write my equation which is like the attached picture.
I tried to write this code below but I couldn't make "Hp" starting from the same positions.

How should I write code to have the picture like this.

```
\begin{eqnarray} \label{eq:5}
Se & = & \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \frac{1}{{[1+|\alpha H_{p}|^{n}]}^{m}}     & \quad H_{p}<0\\
                  1  & \quad H_{p} \geq0
                \end{array}
              \right.   \nonumber
 \\
 \theta & = & \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \theta_{r}+Se(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})  & \quad H_{p}<0\\
                  \theta_{s}     & \quad H_{p} \geq0 
                \end{array}
              \right. 
\\  
C & = & \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\left(1-Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\right)^{m}    & \quad H_{p}<0\\
                  0     & \quad H_{p} \geq0
                \end{array}
              \right.   \nonumber   
\\  
k_{r} & = & \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  Se^{l}\left[1-\left(1-Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\right)^{m} \right]^2   & \quad H_{p}<0\\
                  1     & \quad H_{p} \geq0
                \end{array}
              \right.   \nonumber                                            
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use `eqnarray`! It is deprecated since years. For such things, there are `cases` from `amsmath` or the newer `mathtools`. Just put everything inside of an `align`. The trick in order to align the most right column is to use an `\hphantom` here. I hope, this is what you wanted to have.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\Se}{\operatorname{\mathit{S\kern-.15em e}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \theta &=  
    \begin{dcases}
        \theta_{r}+\Se(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r}) & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathrlap{\theta_{s}}\hphantom{\frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m}} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases}\\
    \Se &=  
    \begin{dcases}
        \frac{1}{{\bigl[1+\lvert\alpha H_{p}\rvert^{n}\bigr]}^{m}} & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathrlap{1}\hphantom{\frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m}} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases} \\
    C &=
    \begin{dcases} 
        \frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m} & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        0 & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases} \\
    k_{r} &= 
    \begin{dcases}
        \Se^{l}\Bigl[1-\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m} \Bigr]^2 & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathrlap{1}\hphantom{\frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m}} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As recommended by daleif, you could also define some certain width and put your lower rows in a `mathmakebox` with left alignment. This would look like:

```
\begin{align*}
    \theta &=  
    \begin{dcases}
        \theta_{r}+\Se(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r}) & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathmakebox[5cm][l]{\theta_{s}} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases}\\
    \Se &=  
    \begin{dcases}
        \frac{1}{{\bigl[1+\lvert\alpha H_{p}\rvert^{n}\bigr]}^{m}} & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathmakebox[5cm][l]{1} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases} \\
    C &=
    \begin{dcases} 
        \frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m} & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathmakebox[5cm][l]{0} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases} \\
    k_{r} &= 
    \begin{dcases}
        \Se^{l}\Bigl[1-\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m} \Bigr]^2 & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mathmakebox[5cm][l]{1} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer, but it is equation that I didn't put it in my screenshot. It is just one equation in total. so, how is it possible to write and having equation number?

Comment: @Sepideh You mean for every line?

Comment: @Sepideh Just remove the asterisk and do something like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17528 if you want just one number.

Comment: No, actually for all of these four functions create one equation in my thesis.

Comment: @Sepideh Replace `align*` with `aligned`, and then wrap it in an `equation` environment, so you have `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} <all the four equations> \end{aligned}\end{equation}`.

Comment: Ok, great. It works but, what does this line means? \newcommand{\Se}{\operatorname{\mathit{S\kern-.15em e}}}

Comment: Instead of all those `\phantoms` wouldn't it be easier (nad easier to understand) if you just wrapped the 1's and 0's in `\mathmakebox` for some common width?

Comment: @Sepideh @Torbjorn T. Just `\begin{align}` should be enough. No `equation` or `aligned` needed. Oh, got it wrong, just one number? Then use `split`. See my link above. @daleif. Sure, would be easier to read. But like this now we have the minimum required width and consistent spacing between `dcases` columns. Maybe there are more cases later in the document that's why I prefer the 'perfect' spacing.

Comment: @Sepideh The Se is just my personal taste. Remove it, if you do not like it. It looks as if `Se` is meant as one variable. So I was thinking about something like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129397

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- the parentheses in the last two parts don't really need to be that big; `\bigl` and `\bigr` would suffice.  then, the brackets in the last part could also be a size smaller.

Comment: @barbarabeeton true, edited.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, sure, but down right isn't that much extra work, and new users can be put off by a solution like this as it contains a lot of redundant code

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I've added an answer where I rewrite your solution a bit.

Comment: @just seen it, posted your comment in my last edit at the same time... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses four `dcases` environments placed inside an `aligned` environment contained in an `equation` environment. I would actually *not* bother providing a common alignment of the four pairs of conditioning statements. Instead, I'd concentrate on (a) not letting some of the individual lines become too tall, e.g., by writing `...^{1/m}` rather than `...^\frac{1}{m}` and (b) providing a bit more vertical whitespace between the four sets of subequations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases'  environment
\newcommand\Se{\textit{Se}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:5}
\begin{aligned}
\Se  &= \begin{dcases}
        \frac{1}{[1+\lvert\alpha H_p \rvert^{n}]^{m}} & H_p<0\\
        1  &  H_p\geq0
        \end{dcases}  \\[2ex]
\theta &= \begin{dcases}
          \theta_{r}+\Se (\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})  & H_p<0\\
          \theta_{s}     & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}\\[2ex]
C &= \begin{dcases}
     \frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se ^{1/m} \bigl(1-\Se ^{1/m}\bigr)^{m}    & H_p<0\\
     0     & H_p\geq0
     \end{dcases}\\[2ex]
k_{r} &= \begin{dcases}
         \Se^{l}\bigl[1-(1-\Se ^{1/m})^{m} \bigr]^2   & H_p<0\\
         1     & H_p\geq0
         \end{dcases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you believe it's preferable to align the four conditioning pairs as well, here's a straightforward way to achieve this goal: (a) Save the longest term in the equations to a macro named, say, `\longestterm` and measure its width; (b) place one term each of subequations 1, 2, and 4 in a `\parbox` whose width is that of `\longestterm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases'  environment
\newcommand\Se{\textit{Se}}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\longestterm{\frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se ^{1/m} (1-\Se ^{1/m}) ^{m}}
\settowidth\mylen{$\displaystyle\longestterm$}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:5}
\begin{aligned}
\Se    &= \begin{dcases}
          \frac{1}{[1+\lvert\alpha H_p\rvert^{n}]^{m}} & H_p<0\\
          \parbox{\mylen}{$1$}  &  H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}  \\[2ex]
\theta &= \begin{dcases}
          \theta_{r}+\Se(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r}) & H_p<0\\
          \parbox{\mylen}{$\theta_{s}$} & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}\\[2ex]
C      &= \begin{dcases}
          \longestterm & H_p<0\\
          0 & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}\\[2ex]
k_{r}  &= \begin{dcases}
          \Se^{l}\bigl[1-(1-\Se^{1/m})^{m} \bigr]^2 & H_p<0\\
          \parbox{\mylen}{$1$}  & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a supplement to LaRiFaRis solution, doing the same thing with less code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\Se}{\operatorname{\mathit{S\kern-.15em e}}}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{}
\begin{document}
% jsut to make this function for this patciluar case 
\renewcommand\mybox[1]{
  \mathrlap{#1}
  \hphantom{\frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m}}
}
\begin{align*}
    \theta &=  
    \begin{dcases}
        \theta_{r}+\Se(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r}) & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mybox{\theta_{s}} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases}\\
    \Se &=  
    \begin{dcases}
        \frac{1}{{\bigl[1+\lvert\alpha H_{p}\rvert^{n}\bigr]}^{m}} & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mybox{1} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases} \\
    C &=
    \begin{dcases} 
        \frac{\alpha
          m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m}
        & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        % this is the widest, so no need to do it here, but we do for
        % completness 
        \mybox{0} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases} \\
    k_{r} &= 
    \begin{dcases}
        \Se^{l}\Bigl[1-\bigl(1-\Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\bigr)^{m} \Bigr]^2 & H_{p}<0 \\ 
        \mybox{1} & H_{p} \geq 0 
    \end{dcases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with `eqparbox`: I define an `\eqmathbox` command, which makes all commands with the same tag have length equal to the longest contents (two compilations required):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' environment
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\newcommand\Se{\textit{Se}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:5}
\begin{aligned}
\Se &= \begin{dcases}
          \eqmathbox{\frac{1}{[1+\lvert\alpha H_p\rvert^{n}]^{m}}} & H_p<0\\
          1 & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases} \\[2ex]
\theta &= \begin{dcases}
          \eqmathbox{\theta_{r}+\Se(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})}
          & H_p<0\\
            \theta_{s} & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}\\[2ex]
C &= \begin{dcases}
          \eqmathbox{\frac{\alpha m}{1-m}(\theta_{s}-\theta_{r})Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\left(1-Se^{\frac{1}{m}}\right)^{m}} & H_p<0\\
          0 & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}\\[2ex]
k_{r} &= \begin{dcases}
          \eqmathbox{\Se^{l}\bigl[1-(1-\Se^{1/m})^{m} \bigr]^2} & H_p<0\\
           1 & H_p\geq0
          \end{dcases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]